# How to share contact by telegram bot via query string

Tags: share, query-string, bots, contacts, telegram-bot

It is possible to send message via query string to any user by telegram bots, but i want to share a contact replace of sending a text message.

is it possible?

how can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean let bot send phone contacts to user?

If you mean that, you can try [sendContact](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendcontact) method instead of `sendMessage`.